# changing patent name on non provisional patent [that is claiming date from provisional application]

Tags: provisional-application, non-provisional, name

Can I change the patent name on my non provisional patent that is claiming the date from the associated provisional application if the new name is no longer the same as the name I used on the provisional?

Answer (score 2):

So long as the new title meets the requirements for patent titles, there should be no problem. Keep in mind that suggested changes to the title may be made to you, so it is already possible that the title will change after your non-provisional has been reviewed.

The title -- name -- of the invention isn't the invention, it is a clear and concise description of what the invention is or does. The "old" and "new" titles should both be kinda close because the non-provisional must make claims related to what was described in the provisional.

Comment: Good answer, but could you clarify one thing? Since a provisional doesn't need to provide claims, wouldn't it be more correct to state "...because the non-provisional must make claims related to what was ***described*** in the provisional."

Comment: That's more accurate.

Comment: And here I am and thought the question was about the name of the inventor haha.

Comment: @DonQuiKong - I've known women who delayed patent filings until after marriages and/or divorces were finalized.